# Using jQuery's $(this) throws an error inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery passing $(this) to other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036647/jquery-passing-this-to-other-functions)

I am writing a Javascript/jQuery function (NOT REFACTORED YET) but I am getting an error from using `$(this)`. It's a little difficult to explain so I'll add the code and hopefully it will become more clear:

```
var accordion = 'div.accordionContent';
var accordButton = 'div.accordionButton';
var accordClosedArrow = 'url(/public/img/accordion-closed-arrow-';
var accordOpenArrow = 'url(/public/img/accordion-open-arrow-';
$(accordion).hide();
var accordFunc = function(arrowColor){
    var img;
    if ($(this).next(accordion).is(':visible')) {
        img = accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
    } 
    else {
        img = accordOpenArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
    }

    // these lines throw errors because of $(this)
    $(this).css({backgroundImage:img}).next().slideToggle('slow').siblings(accordion)
        .slideUp();
    $(this).siblings()
        .css({backgroundImage:accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)' + 'no-repeat'});
    };

    $(accordButton).live('click',function(){
        accordFunc('blue');
    });

    $(accordButton + 'B').live('click',function(){
        accordFunc('orange');
    });
```

Not sure why passing `$(this)` causes the Chrome console to throw an error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined**

Comment: dear lord, wrap `$(this)` once and reuse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `accordFunc('blue');` with `accordFunc.call(this, 'blue');` and do likewise for the other call to that function.

The `this` value is not preserved when you call another function so inside `accordFunc` it points to the window object or null (if strict mode is active). Another option would be passing `this` as a normal argument and changing the function definition e.g. to `function accordFunc(elem, arrowColor)` and use `elem` instead of `this` inside that function.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I'm a bit of a JS noob. why do I need the .call?

Comment: See the docs on it - it invokes a function with its `this` bound to the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in a method in JS, the scope of `this` changes back to the window. It is strange behavior but that's the way it works unfortunately! Try passing the context you require through as parameter to the method like so:

```
        var accordFunc = function(ctx, arrowColor){
          var img;
          if ($(ctx).next(accordion).is(':visible')) {
                  img = accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
          } 
          else {
              img = accordOpenArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
          }

          // these lines throw errors because of $(this)    
          $(ctx).css({backgroundImage:img}).next().slideToggle('slow').siblings(accordion).slideUp();
          $(ctx).siblings().css({backgroundImage:accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)'     + 'no-repeat'});
        };

        $(accordButton).live('click',function(){
            accordFunc(this, 'blue');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to make accordFunc to return the function that will be binded, and use closure to the color:

```
var accordFunc = function(arrowColor){
    return function(){
        var img;
        if ($(this).next(accordion).is(':visible')) {
            img = accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
        } 
        else {
            img = accordOpenArrow + arrowColor + '.png)';
        }

        // these lines throw errors because of $(this)
        $(this).css({backgroundImage:img}).next().slideToggle('slow').siblings(accordion)
        .slideUp();
        $(this).siblings()
            .css({backgroundImage:accordClosedArrow + arrowColor + '.png)' + 'no-repeat'});
    }
};
```

And then call:

```
$(accordButton + 'B').live('click', accordFunc('orange'));
```